# Automated testing of nested packages

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, package

I am sorry for the dumb question, but I have been banging my head against a wall for past two hours.

I want to use relative imports and my project structure looks like this:

```
auto_testing
+ tests
  + __init__.py
  + my_module.py
+ src
  + __init__.py
  + my_module.py
+ __init__.py
```

The contents of `tests/my_module.py` are:

```
import unittest

from src.my_module import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.inst = MyClass()

    def test_division_by_zero(self):
        self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, self.inst.divide, 1, 0)

def run_tests():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

Then I run commands in terminal

```
cd auto_testing
python3 -m tests.my_module
```

and get `Error while finding spec for 'tests.my_module.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__')`.

When I run

```
cd auto_testing
python3
import tests.my_module
tests.my_module.run_tests()
```

I get `Ran 0 tests` (why no tests were found should be another question, but the point is, that `MyClass` is imported properly and `unittest.main()` seems to be called; checked with `print`).

Should I go sleeping for I missed something very simple?

Answer (score 0):

I should have went sleeping.

The commands I needed to run were:

```
cd auto_testing
python3 -m unittest tests/my_module.py
```

This also runs my tests.